# Alignment issue in election nomination editor toolbar

Tags: bug, design, election

There is an alignment issue in the election nomination editor toolbar.

I have verified the issue, it is exists in the following browsers:

- Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m
- Mozilla Firefox Version 48.0
- Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.18205

[image: Nomination editor]